# Create an interface file for a DVD with plenty of documents in it

Tags: html, hyperlink, interface

I’m not sure about the problem which is explained below, is appropriate for programming with **html**.

Assume that I have a DVD and a plenty of document files that are burned in DVD. I’m going to create an **interface** file for users to use the content of DVD easily. When one inserts the disk into machine, the interface file is automatically run by Autorun file (existed in disk). The interface file, also, has as much hyperlinks as number of documents and for each document there is one corresponding selection with appropriate hyperlink in interface file. The user accesses to all documents of disk by clicking on the hyperlinks.

How can I do this? Any comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best option will be using dedicated software. There are many applications available, for example [DVD Styler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/).